# Django queryset for list item

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-queryset

I am still fairly new to django and I ran into a problem which I am having a hard time figuring out even with using google or maybe I am not seeing the solution. So I have a model named movieTitles like so:

```
class movieTitle(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    director = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

Then I have my view as so:

```
from Movie.models import movieTitles

def movieListView(request):
    movie = movieTitle.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'movies':movie})
```

and my html as so:

```
<body>
    {% for info in movies %}
        <a href="#">{{info.title}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

What I want it to do is once user goes to the movie list and they decide to click on a certain movie, how can I take the user to another html page which will show the `info.image`, `info.description`, `info.year`, and `info.director` belonging to the movie they decided to click on. I know how to write the template and all that but what im confused on is how can I write the template using {{info.???}} and not having to create a template for every movie to link to but instead use the previous template in which the user chose a movie to create the details in the next template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new view, which get a pk of choosen movie and retrives all informations about it.

```
# Add to urls.py

urlpatterns += [url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.movie_detail, name='movie_detail')]

# Add to views.py

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def movie_detail(request, pk):
    movie = get_object_or_404(movieTitle, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'movie_detail.html', {'movie': movie})

# movie_detail.html

<h1>Title: {{ movie.title }}</h1>
<img src="{{ movie.image }}">
{{ movie.description|linebreaks }}
<p>Year: {{ movie.year }}</p>
<p>Director: {{ movie.director }}</p>
```

Last thing you should do is to put right url in html with movie list

```
# Your initial html
<body>
    {% for movie in movies %}
        <a href="{% url 'movie_detail' movie.pk %}">{{ movie.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

And that's all

Answer (score -1):

add a unique field in ur model like id foreg:-

```
class movieTitle(models.Model):
    id = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    director = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

and amke a url like this:
supppose app name is:

```
app_name = 'movie'
```

`url(r'^movie-list/show/(?P<university_id>[0-9]+)/$', view.view_list, name='view-list')`,

and pass ur url in template like this:

```
<body>
    {% for info in movies %}
        <a href="{{movie:view-list}} info.id">{{info.title}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```